# Why does Windows File Explorer take more time to open from the task bar than from a keyboard macro?

Tags: keyboard, windows-explorer, windows-10

If I open a File Explorer window by clicking on it on the task bar (either left click if none is open or middle click if one is already open), it takes about a second or two until the window opens. This isn't much, but it's a noticeable slowdown.

I am using Windows 10 and File Explorer is set to open This PC instead of Quick Access. I'm on an i5 laptop with an SSD. I have upgraded from a Windows 8.1 installation, which had the same behavior from the beginning.

If I use a keyboard macro for a Logitech G710+ keyboard that is set to open "My Computer", which has the effect of opening This PC, the window shows up instantly once I press the assigned key. I am not sure what this macro does internally, because it's a preset that I just select in the Logitech software.

Can I make File Explorer open faster when clicking on it?

Why is there a noticeable difference between the two startup speeds?

**Update 28.08.2015**

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63577993/explorer%20startup.zip) are the xperf results requested in the comments.

Comment: follow this: http://pastebin.com/SY9gvPbu and give me the 2 xperf traces so that I can compare them.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have added the link to the results to my question: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63577993/explorer%20startup.zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I compared both traces and found 1 difference. When you start Explorer via Taskbar, some nvidia shell extension files (`nv3dappshext.dll`, `nvapi64.dll`) get loaded when Windows loads the context menus (`shell32.dll!HDXA_QueryContextMenu`):

```
Line #, Process, Stack Tag, Stack, Count, Weight (in view), TimeStamp, % Weight
9, , ,   |    |    |    explorer.exe!CTaskBand::CLauncherTask::_Launch, 645, 645,322890, , 2,14
10, , ,   |    |    |    |- explorer.exe!LaunchNewInstanceWithOptionalElevate, 642, 642,320335, , 2,13
11, , ,   |    |    |    |    shlwapi.dll!SHInvokeCommandWithFlagsAndSite, 642, 642,320335, , 2,13
12, , ,   |    |    |    |    shlwapi.dll!SHInvokeCommandOnContextMenu2, 642, 642,320335, , 2,13
13, , ,   |    |    |    |    |- shell32.dll!CDefFolderMenu::QueryContextMenu, 626, 626,236799, , 2,08
14, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |- shell32.dll!HDXA_QueryContextMenu, 625, 625,236799, , 2,08
15, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |- nv3dappshext.dll!?, 619, 619,161526, , 2,06
16, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    nv3dappshext.dll!?, 619, 619,161526, , 2,06
17, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    nv3dappshext.dll!?, 619, 619,161526, , 2,06
18, , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    nvapi64.dll!?, 619, 619,161526, , 2,06
```

The hotkey trace doesn't show this nvidia DLL load. Use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable the nVIDIA extensions.

Comment: I can't find any `nvapi64.dll` in ShellExView, but I did disable everything I could find relating to Nvidia: **NvAppShExt Class, NVIDIA CPL Context Menu Extension, OpenGLShExt Class, DesktopContext Class**. This fixed the issue.

Comment: nice to hear that you were able to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

In safe mode seems to be ok. It seems some problem with nvidia graphic card. I found a workaround, problem is gone if you disable contextual menu nvidia options.

Go to nVidia Control (right click on desktop -> nvidia control panel). Then in menu bar choose Desktop and UNSELECT "Add Desktop Context Menu" and "Add run with Graphics Processor". After this, even without reboot, problem seems to be gone and file explorer is way faster from taskbar...

Source: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1139638-file-explorer-slow-to-open-from-taskbar/?do=findComment&comment=596672310